# Where are the JavaScript field definitions?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP form that includes javascript js_qty.js.  Js_qty_.js has this function called xhrGetValue.

I am in my NetBeans IDE and it shows the field definitions for f.job_id, f.item_id, etc.  I have looked in the JavaScript and the HTML portion of the PHP and I cannot find the field definitions.

Where else could I look to find the field definitions?

```
function xhrGetValue(field) {
//eval('document.forms[0].'+field+'.value=document.forms[0].'+field+'_value.value');
var r='GetValue';
var url = "job_qty_xhrr.php"; // The server-side script
var f=document.forms[0];
var param = 'p_id='+f.p_id.value+'&job_id='+f.job_id.value+'&r='+r+'&field='+field+'&item_id='+f.item_id.value+'&sub_id='+f.sub_id.value+'&qty_id='+f.qty_id.value;
http.open("GET", url+'?'+param, true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHRGetValue
http.send(null);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var f=document.forms[0];
```

Tells you p_id and job_id are coming from the first form in your document (page).  Check the html again or check to see if the fields are being generated by javascript.

Comment: I looked in the JavaScript and the php form that included the JavaScript.  Are these my only choices?

Comment: You've looked at all the HTML markup for the form? Try searching for job_id in all your project files?

Comment: My PHP project has over 800 modules and job_id is very common across the website.  I'll try to find a less commonly used field and continue searching.  Thanks for your help.